# Messaging correlation and syncing

Tags: c#, thread-safety, event-handling

We use masstransit and sagas. But I also wanted to correlate some messages without the need for a saga since the syntax for those are pretty verbose if all your need is to sync on a correlation id.

First I wrote a little handler that does the close to the metal stuff

```
internal sealed class SyncedScope : ISyncedScope
{
    private readonly DbContext _db;

    public SyncedScope(DbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public async Task RunSynced<TData>(Func<TData, Task> task, Guid correlationId, TData data)
    {
        var trans = await _db.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();

        try
        {
            await _db.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(@"EXEC sp_getapplock  
@DbPrincipal='public',  
@Resource={0},  
@LockMode='Exclusive',  
@LockOwner='Transaction';", correlationId);
            await task(data);
        }
        finally
        {
            await trans.CommitAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Then the implementation of the above class. We have a mechanic were we can map external events to internal commands and its only for us we want this light weight correlation mechanic. Note that we create a seperate scope for the dependency since we dont want the db transaction to affect the domain DbContext and locking domain tables.

```
private class CommandMapperConsumer<TExternal, TCommand> : IConsumer<TExternal> where TExternal : class where TCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly ExternalMap<TExternal, TCommand> _mapping;
    private readonly ICqsRunner _cqsRunner;
    private readonly IMessageScope _scope;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public CommandMapperConsumer(ExternalMap<TExternal, TCommand> mapping, ICqsRunner cqsRunner, IMessageScope scope, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _mapping = mapping;
        _cqsRunner = cqsRunner;
        _scope = scope;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<TExternal> context)
    {
        if (!await _scope.BeginScope(context)) return;

        if (_mapping.CorrelateBy != null)
        {
            using var serviceScope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
            await serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ISyncedScope>().RunSynced(ctx => ExecuteCommand(ctx.Message), _mapping.CorrelateBy(context.Message), context);

            return;
        }

        await ExecuteCommand(context.Message);
    }

    private Task ExecuteCommand(TExternal @event)
    {
        return _cqsRunner.ExecuteCommandAsync(_mapping.Mapper(@event));
    }
}
```

Setup helper

```
public ICqsConfigurator MapExternalEvent<TExternal, TCommand>(Func<TExternal, TCommand> mapper, Func<TExternal, Guid>? correlateBy = null) where TExternal : class where TCommand : ICommand
    {
        _services.AddSingleton(new ExternalMap<TExternal, TCommand>(mapper, correlateBy));
        BusConfig.AddConsumer<CommandMapperConsumer<TExternal, TCommand>, SubscriptionFilterDefinition<TExternal, CommandMapperConsumer<TExternal, TCommand>>>().Endpoint(cfg => cfg.ConfigureEndpointName("external", BusConfig));
        
        return this;
    }
```

Domain code

```
cqs.MapExternalEvent<MessageResponseEvent, MessageResponseCommand>(m => new MessageResponseCommand{ TxId = m.TxId, DocumentId = m.DocumentId }, m => m.TxId);
```

Biggest problem with the code as I see it is the reliance on `IServiceProvider`, but since its not domain code but rather plumbing code I think its ok.